# Column name conflicting with parent class name in JPA criteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa

I have a class which is an entity and a child class inherited from it, but it has field which is same as parent class name.

**eg:**

```
@Entity
class Parent {
    String parentField;
}

@Entity
class Child extends Parent {
    String parent;
}
```

Now when I need to do a JPA Query like as follows:

```
Root<Child> childClassRoot = criteriaBuilder.treat(parentRoot, Child.class);
criteriaQuery.select(parentRoot).where(
    criteriaBuilder.like(childClassRoot.get("parent"), "%someText%")
)
```

Is not working for me, because JPA thinks parent is not child.parent, but the parent class. When I rename the parent to parentText then it works fine.

So if I modify the child class and use following query then it works fine:

```
@Entity
class Child extends Parent {
    String parentText;
}
```

and query:

```
criteriaQuery.select(parentRoot).where(
    criteriaBuilder.like(childClassRoot.get("parentText"), "%someText%")
)
```

that works,

but is there any solution where I don't need to rename the column name ? I mean I can rename the column to fix this, but is there any alternative ?

Comment: Strange because I can do exactly like that with the JPA provider I use, and the parent class and this field do NOT have the same name; one has capitalised letter ... case sensitive here. "JPA" is not responsible for this ... your chosen JPA provider is (which you don't mention). And no there is no need to rename anything. And a "column" name is not of any relevance in JPQL or JPA criteria ... they use FIELD names

Comment: Thanks for clearing billyfrost, actually I realized it happens when multiple child classes have same fields, for example ChildOne and ChildTwo class inherited from same parent , both child classes same same field, I thought its just because of Parent class, but now that you are saying, so I am dead sure about the child classes having common field (although it should have been in the parent class as its common field for child classes but not all child classes, anyways that is different topic), anyways I renamed the columns, so my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

There is no other solution except renaming it.

Comment: except that they arent the same name ... in a case sensitive world